# Iterations with Loops and Functions

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I wanted to run a loop that read the value in a dataframe (data_rais), but I realised it might take days and I think is due to fact that I'm running a loop, and not a function.
I tried several times to write a function that does the same as this loop, but I couldn't find a way to do so. 
My question is: Is it possible to transform this loop in a function? How?

```
   for(i in 1:nrow(data_rais)){
  if(is.na(data_rais$postal_code[i])){
    next()
  } else {
    data_rais$munic_name[i] = munics_code[row(munics_code)[which(munics_code$cods == data_rais$munic[i])], 1]
  }
}
```

`munics_code` looks like this:

```
  munics_code = tibble::tribble(
    ~municipio,~cods,
    'BELFORD ROXO', 261,
    'DUQUE DE CAXIAS', 250,
    'DUQUE DE CAXIAS', 251,
    'DUQUE DE CAXIAS', 252,
    'DUQUE DE CAXIAS', 253,
    'DUQUE DE CAXIAS', 254,
    'ITABORAÍ', 248,
    'ITAGUAÍ', 2380,
    'ITAGUAÍ', 2381,
    'ITAGUAÍ', 2382,
    'ITAGUAÍ', 2383,
    'ITAGUAÍ', 2384,
    'MAGÉ', 259,
    'MANGARATIBA',2386,
    'MANGARATIBA',2387,
    'MANGARATIBA',2388,
    'MARICÁ',249,
    'MESQUITA',2655)
```

And `data_rais$postal_code` is a column of a data_frame with numbers that may or may not start with the numbers in the cods column in `munics_code`.
Something like...

```
data_rais = data.frame(postal_code = c(2049253, 2033069, 2293513, 2411920, 2284937, 2341811, 2008638, 
                                       2279827, NA, 2386135, 2441900, 2392889, 2332114, 2254610, 
                                       2114414, 2089509, 2351781, 2451466, 2111632, 2070417, 2079485, 
                                       2328146, 2200329, 2116103, NA, 2449114, 2231708, NA, 
                                       NA, 2194253),
                       munic_name = NA)
```

Note: I cannot delete the NAs, I don't want to lose them.

Comment: `match` might be your friend :-)

Comment: @Base_R_Best_R I wish I could, but it isn't possible since I'm dealing with sensitive data.

Comment: If the data is sensitive, create a mock up data set with the same columns of interest.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to do that.

Comment: "may or may not start with the numbers in the cods column in `munics_code`"  does this mean you need partial matching of the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use `match`

```r
data_rais$munic_name = munic_code[[1]][match(data_rais$munic,munic_code$cods)]
```

to take care of entries when you already have a match in `data_rais` use the following:

```r
data_rais$munic_name[!is.na(data_rais$postal_code)] = munic_code[[1]][match(data_rais$munic[!is.na(data_rais$postal_code)],munic_code$cods)]
```

Not sure if you need the second approach, but be careful with overriding original variables. If you're unsure add another variable and inspect the matching manually for a few entries.

Comment: that's true :-) I rarely use this notation, and would normally suggest to use `$` notation, also to be more consistent. I just got confused since the OP has different spellings of data frame and variable names...
I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that my original answer might override already placed entries, where you don't have a match in the data frame to match to but already have an entry in your original `data_rais`

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your code correctly, you are trying to set the `data_rais$munic_name` column to the corresponding `municipio`. This could be done with a merge:

```
df = merge(x = data_rais, y = munics_code, by.x = "postal_code", by.y = "cods", all.x = TRUE)
```

By doing a left merge (`all.x = T`) you'll preserve the NAs in `data_rais`. Assign the merge to `data_rais` if you want to add this column to it.